# Rotate rectangle around its center

Tags: c++, qt

I need to rotate a rectangle around it's center-point and display it in the center of a QWidget. Can you complete this specific code? If possible, could you also dumb-down the explaination or provide a link to the simplest explaination?

Please note: I have read the Qt documentation, compiled examples/demos that deal with rotation and I STILL cannot understand it!

```
void Canvas::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
    QPainter paint(this);

    paint.setBrush(Qt::transparent);
    paint.setPen(Qt::black);
    paint.drawLine(this->width()/2, 0, this->width()/2, this->height());
    paint.drawLine(0, this->height()/2, this->width(), this->height()/2);

    paint.setBrush(Qt::white);
    paint.setPen(Qt::blue);

    // Draw a 13x17 rectangle rotated to 45 degrees around its center-point
    // in the center of the canvas.

    paint.drawRect(QRect(0,0, 13, 17));

}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
 void paintEvent(QPaintEvent* event){
    QPainter painter(this);

    // xc and yc are the center of the widget's rect.
    qreal xc = width() * 0.5;
    qreal yc = height() * 0.5;

    painter.setPen(Qt::black);

    // draw the cross lines.
    painter.drawLine(xc, rect().top(), xc, rect().bottom());
    painter.drawLine(rect().left(), yc, rect().right(), yc);

    painter.setBrush(Qt::white);
    painter.setPen(Qt::blue);

    // Draw a 13x17 rectangle rotated to 45 degrees around its center-point
    // in the center of the canvas.

    // translates the coordinate system by xc and yc
    painter.translate(xc, yc);

    // then rotate the coordinate system by 45 degrees
    painter.rotate(45);

    // we need to move the rectangle that we draw by rx and ry so it's in the center.
    qreal rx = -(13 * 0.5);
    qreal ry = -(17 * 0.5);
    painter.drawRect(QRect(rx, ry, 13, 17));
  }
```

You are in the painter's coordinate system.  When you call drawRect(x, y, 13, 17), it's upper left corner is at `(x,y)`.  If you want `(x, y)` to be the center of your rectangle, then you need to move the rectangle by half, hence `rx` and `ry`.

You can call `resetTransform()` to reset the transformations that were made by `translate()` and `rotate()`.

Comment: I *think* I understand what's going on now. Painter ALWAYS starts at 0,0 no matter what. So when you translate to 100,100 Painter still starts at 0,0 but the new 0,0 now happens to be 100,100?

Answer (score 5):

Simple:

```
void rotate(QPainter* p, const QRectF& r, qreal angle, bool clock_wise) {
    p->translate(r.center());
    p->rotate(clock_wise ? angle : -angle);
    p->translate(-r.center());
}
```